# How can I make an image with this kind of data in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm using the `getID3()` function (available at 
https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3) for getting the image cover of 
MP3 files.

I'm using this part of the code for that:

```
$path="mp3/3.mp3";
require_once('getid3/getid3.php');
$getID3 = new getID3;
$getID3->setOption(array('encoding'=>$TextEncoding)); 
$ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($path);
getid3_lib::CopyTagsToComments($ThisFileInfo);  

$info=$ThisFileInfo['comments'];
$TextEncoding = 'UTF-8';

$data=$info['picture'][0]['data'];
$mime_type=$info['picture'][0]['image_mime'];
$im_width=$info['picture'][0]['image_width'];
$im_height=$info['picture'][0]['image_height'];
```

For showing the image, I use this:

```
echo'<html><body>'."\n".'<tr><td><img src="data:'.$mime_type.';base64,'.base64_encode($data).'" width="'.$im_width.'" height="'.$im_height.'"></td></tr></body></html>'."\n";
```

But nothing is showing.

I want to save `$data` as an image file.

How can I do that?

Comment: You say 'nothing is showing', but what does the actual HTML look like? Is there any data in the img src attribute? Does it have the mime type you expect? Is it the length you expect?

Answer (score 2):

To simply create an image file from a string, or from any format you need the `gd` extension for php.

> **FROM STRING**

```
$toFilePath = '/path/to/save/data/filename';  
//notice the missing file extension.It will be added according to the mime_type.
//Make sure you have the write rights to the folder/file above

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);  //create image data from the string

if ($im !== false) {  //if the image creation is successful
    switch($mime_type) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/jpg':
             imagejpg($im, $toFilePath.'.jpg', 100);
             break;
        case 'image/png':
             imagepng($im, $toFilePath . '.png');
             break;
        case 'image/gif':
             imagegif($im, $toFilePath . '.gif');
             break;
        case 'image/bmp':
             imagebmp($im, $toFilePath . '.bmp');
             break;
    }
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

> **FROM BLOB/BINARY DATA** (*The code snippets below are tailored specifically for this library.*)

```
$toFilePath = '/path/to/save/data/filename';  
//notice the missing file extension.It will be added according to the mime_type.
//Make sure you have the write rights to the folder/file above

switch($mime_type) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
    case 'image/jpg':
        $toFilePath .= '.jpg';
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        $toFilePath .=  '.png';
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $toFilePath .=  '.gif';
        break;
    case 'image/bmp':
        $toFilePath .=  '.bmp';
        break;
}
if ($handle = fopen($toFilePath, 'wb')) {
    fwrite($handle, $data);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

The code is taken from https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3/blob/master/demos/demo.mp3header.php and stripped down to fit the needs of OP

> **EXTRACT ALL THE IMAGES FROM THE FILE**

```
function extractImages($pictureInfo) {
    $toFilePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'output' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'filename';
    //notice the missing file extension.It will be added according to the mime_type.
    //Make sure you have the write rights to the folder/file above

    for ($i = 0, $count = count($pictureInfo);$i < $count;$i++) {

        $data = $pictureInfo[$i]['data'];
        $mime_type = $pictureInfo[$i]['image_mime'];

        switch ($mime_type) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/jpg':
                $toFilePath .= '_' . $i . '.jpg';
                break;
            case 'image/png':
                $toFilePath .= '_' . $i . '.png';
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $toFilePath .= '_' . $i . '.gif';
                break;
            case 'image/bmp':
                $toFilePath .= '_' . $i . '.bmp';
                break;
        }
        if ($handle = fopen($toFilePath, 'wb')) {
            fwrite($handle, $data);
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}

$path = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "mp3" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "3.mp3";
require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'getid3' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'getid3.php');
$TextEncoding = 'UTF-8';
$getID3 = new getID3();
$getID3->setOption(array('encoding' => $TextEncoding));
$ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($path);

getid3_lib::CopyTagsToComments($ThisFileInfo);

$info = $ThisFileInfo['comments'];

if (isset($info['picture'])) extractImages($info['picture']);
else {
    echo 'no picture tag';
}
```

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: (PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format). my $data is sth like "????JFIF``?????C=????zS???????A?C?v???k????fI??<�?\?s????o?[??_j?}-w??|[??Y X q:}Ӹ??*?z[]Y5?6???؅???S1?I$?9J%FR%E????T?I%9?ԛz?N??mF?L?h???:բ?kwo?tD?'IK9?h??̧LZ ??|W???cc?\?tt?Pɢ???0J?n???{?=VW???????2J{&?S^Ɔ?3q???w? ?}?6??.y.,}???%?????O?????U??:]g.ܱ[zuk?l??K}-,v??}6?:??????̯?V?Ye??7 ??????\???????Se*S?]?U??/?ޏwRȇ9??z??R?5P????)?,_?׷??jn?o^??_??]????.........................".

Comment: can anybody help?

Comment: Well you need to read the answer better mate. The first part is for creating an image from string, as yours is a binary data `$im` is always false. You need to use the second part.

Comment: image was created.but i have #1 image  instead #2 .

#1 image http://uupload.ir/files/cch1_capxzczxczxcture.png
#2   http://uupload.ir/files/l5ns_dddfd.png

Comment: Mate, I don't put the data in there. This function basically does what you asked. Create image from the binary output created by `getID3` library. Why you have the image #1 instead of #2 is for the scope of another question. SO requires one question per thread, so everyone can find exactly what they need. Since the image is created from the data the library presents, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Just to make a guess, I'd go ahead and say that your file contains more than one image. You might want to loop in `$data=$info['picture']` and extract only what you need

Comment: i Appreciate. thank u so much. when i open that image nothing is showing

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding you. I updated my answer to extract all the images since you posted the screenshots of an image that was extracted via the code I provided telling me that the code works.

Comment: Can you add the mp3 you are trying so i can give it a shot on my machine

Comment: Now I have updated the answer (3rd part, all the code you need is there). Tested that it's working. Also tested that you either didn't try at all, or tried to copy something else as the last portion had minor snytax errors, and you should have received `Notice: Undefined index: picture in...`. The function needs a folder named `output` on the same level with the php file.